# Adding Image To Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to add a case flag to a custom lightning component.

Flag Field

```
IF(ISNULL(FLAGS__ViewedFlag__c),null, 
IF(FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age__c > (IF(ISBLANK(FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset4__c) , 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__TimeOffset4__c,FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset4__c)), 
IMAGE( "https://fuze-- 
fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?flagsort=" & 
FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age_Text__c & "&file=" & 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__Offset4Image__c, "L4", 16, 16), 
IF(FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age__c >= (IF(ISBLANK(FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset3__c ), 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__TimeOffset3__c,FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset3__c)), 
IMAGE( "https://fuze-- 
fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?flagsort=" & 
FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age_Text__c & "&file=" & 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__Offset3Image__c, "L3", 16, 16), 
IF(FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age__c >= (IF(ISBLANK(FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset2__c ), 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__TimeOffset2__c,FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset2__c)), 
IMAGE( "https://fuze-- 
fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?flagsort=" & 
FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age_Text__c & "&file=" & 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__Offset2Image__c, "L2", 16, 16), 
IF(FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age__c >= (IF(ISBLANK(FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset1__c ), 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__TimeOffset1__c,FLAGS__CaseTimeOffset1__c)), 
IMAGE( "https://fuze-- 
fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?flagsort=" & 
FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age_Text__c & "&file=" & 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__Offset1Image__c, "L1",16,16), 
IMAGE( "https://fuze-- 
fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?flagsort=" & 
FLAGS__Case_Flag_Age_Text__c &"&file=" & 
$Setup.FLAGS__FlagPref__c.FLAGS__BlankOffsetImage__c, "L0",16,16)) 
))) 
)
```

If I use

```
<lightning:formattedText value="{!item.Flag_New__c}"/></p>
```

I get

```
<img src="https://fuze-- 
 fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload? 
 flagsort=00063033&amp; file=015a0000003xHlrAAE" alt="L4" style="height:16px; 
 width:16px;" border="0"/>
```

If I use formattedURL I get the following

```
 http://<img src="https://fuze-- 
 fullfuze1.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload? 
 flagsort=00063060&amp; file=015a0000003xHlrAAE" alt="L4" 
 style="height:16px; width:16px;" border="0"/>
```

How do I remove the &amp that's being returned so that the image displays properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are directly getting the `HTML` markup you can use [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification)

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!item.Flag_New__c}" />
```

---

However, if you are not using list of records, I would recommend to use `outputField`:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="00128000009j45uAAA"
                              objectApiName="Account">
        <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:outputField fieldName="My_Image__c" />
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Comment: Thanks the first answer worked beautifully.